# Magento - re-position block/element in shopping cart

Tags: xml, magento, layout, cart

I have bought a custom extension to use in my shopping cart but i want to change the position.
At the moment the element/block is positioned underneath the whole cart form where as i want it to be placed right under or inside the coupon code block as shown in this pic:

[image]
The extension xml file to originally position the extension is:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
  <reference name="content">
        <block type="ext/custom" name="ext.custom"></block>         
  </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

In my checkout.xml file my coupon section looks like:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        ......
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
        </block>
        ......
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension is referencing the wrong block to be in that position.  It needs to referenced the appropriate parent. In your code you have it referencing "content" which would place it at the highest level on the page.   So by moving it to checkout.cart your placing it in the auxiliary box you are pointing out.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
  <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="ext/custom" name="ext.custom"></block>         
  </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

I originally thought that cart.phtml listed all its children automatically, however it does not. Additionally using before and after is not necessary because you position the child blocks within the template file by calling them uniquely.

Open cart.phtml in your theme and call your block below coupon

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ext.custom') ?>
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've just tried this but when i make the changes the block now disappears from the page altogether. I'm using a custom theme so i also reverted back to the default magento store just incase i had any conflictions with my theme but it is still not showing. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer so this should resolve your issue.

Comment: How odd this is still not working. Nothing gets added. Cache is disabled but also cleared my cache just incase and added an `as="ext_custom"` identifier in the xml file and using that in the `getChildHtml` but still nothing

Comment: How is the template being set?  Is it programmatically being added in the custom block type?

Comment: As far as I can tell the block is only being called in the extensions own xml file. There is no reference calling the block in any of the cart phtml files